# Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be non zero linear transformation from $V$ to $W$.

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be non zero linear transformation from $V$ to $W$. Consider

P: If $R(T_1) \cap R(T_2) = \{0\}$ then $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linearly independent.

Q: If $N(T_1) \cap N(T_2) = \{0\}$ then $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linearly independent.

1. P and Q both are false.
2. P and Q both are true.
3. P is true and Q is false.
4. P is false and Q is true.

Please hint me, how to initiate the solution.

Comment: What are $R$ and $N?$ What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Range space and Null space.

Comment: What about your thoughts?

Comment: I think that $N(T_1) \cap N(T_2) = \{0\}$ then $T_1 $ and $T_2$ should be one one. But I don't know linear independence of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Comment: Are you aware that $\mathrm{Hom}_K(V,W)$ is a vector space? What is then a linear combination of two homomorphisms?

By the way: Why should $T_1$ and $T_2$ be injective?

Comment: $Hom_K(V,W)$ is a set of all linear transformations from $V$ to $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST CLAIM**

Since $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are non zero linear transformations from $V$ to $W$, there are $v_{1}\in V$ and $v_{2}\in V$, where $v_{1}\neq 0$ and $v_{2}\neq 0$, such that $T(v_{1}) \neq 0$ and $T(v_{2}) \neq 0$. Consequently, one has that

\begin{align*}
\alpha T_{1}(v_{1}) + \beta T_{2}(v_{2}) = 0 & \Rightarrow \alpha T_{1}(v_{1}) = -\beta T_{2}(v_{2})\\\\
& \Rightarrow \alpha T_{1}(v_{1})\in T_{1}(V)\cap T_{2}(V) = \{0\}\\\\
& \Rightarrow \alpha T_{1}(v_{1}) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \alpha = 0 
\end{align*}

Similar reasoning leads to the conclusion that $\beta = 0$.

Hence, if $T_{1}(V)\cap T_{2}(V) = \{0\}$, $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are LI.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Your hint is very nice. Please elaborate "$\Rightarrow \alpha T_{1}(v_{1})\in T_{1}(V)\cap T_{2}(V) $"

Comment: This is because $\alpha T_{1}(v_{1}) = -\beta T_{2}(v_{2})$, where the last expression belongs to $T_{2}(V)$.